# Error with fabletools forecast, Can't combine <yearweek> with different `week_start`

Tags: forecast, fabletools

I have tsibble data with year-week and sales quantity. The year-week is of week type which starts on a Saturday (default tsibble yearweek starts on Monday). I have the fit models using fabletools::model. However when I try to fit for the next 2 weeks I'm getting the following

```
Error: Can't combine <yearweek> with different `week_start`.
```

Comment: I changed global options for the default week start, but still getting the same error

Comment: Was able to stop it from throwing the error by using the default week start date (Monday). However the problem I'm working on considers Saturday as the week start date for sales and deliveries and hence would still like to find a way of doing that. Do let me know how (if) this can be achieved. Thanks in advance.